# Math symbols in the text of a reference make xr-hyper crash

Tags: xetex, cross-referencing, unicode-math, xr, xr-hyper

I want to typeset cross-references from an external document, using `xr-hyper`. This raises an error as soon as there are mathematical symbols in the text of some reference in the external document.

Here is a MWE reproducing the error as I initially obtained it.

```
% FILE PREAMBLE.TEX

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[stixtwo]{fontsetup}
\usepackage{cleveref}
```

```
% FILE EXTERNAL.TEX

% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\input{preamble}

\begin{document}
Here's an equation:
\begin{equation} \label{my-equation}
    0 = 1 \tag{$\Gamma$}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

```
% FILE MAIN.TEX

% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\input{preamble}
\externaldocument{external}

\begin{document}
Hello world, see \cref{my-equation}.
\end{document}
```

The error in `main.log` is as follows:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> {{$\mitGamma 
                        $}}{1}
l.5 
    
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. (...)

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> {[equation][2147483647][]{$\mitGamma 
                                                $}}{[1][1][]1}
l.5 
    
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. (...)

(./main.aux)
\openout1 = `main.aux'.
```

It looks aas if `xr-hyper` did not see that `unicode-math` has been loaded (*via* `fontsetup`). Am I right? And is there any fix?

Comment: works ok for me. Show the external.aux and the full log of the main compilation.

Comment: Here are `external.aux`: https://paste.chapril.org/?8edcd3496f7de39c#7TwZrnKgw5XMVZEpv4n9sDu3KAGK6d9GCi2HDs15HosE, and `main.log`: https://paste.chapril.org/?87313e34b5291c51#7cHLybVHRBrF9gkETnPJqr5xSwV5vpUsy9v2UhBJu5dp.

Comment: your tex system is not up-to-date. In a current texlive 2024 (or 2023) it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out that moving `\externadocument` after `\begin{document}` solves the problem, *i.e.*

```
% FILE MAIN.TEX

% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\input{preamble}

\begin{document}
\externaldocument{external}
Hello world, see \cref{my-equation}.
\end{document}
```

`unicode-math` seems to define `\mitGamma` only at `\begin{document}`, hence importing the references from `external.aux` before caused an error. (Or maybe I'm mistaken?)

Comment: you are using an older xr-hyper which had a bug and expanded commands to early, see https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/327.

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed I'm using texlive as provided by Mint's repos, I'm a few versions behind...